# Does incoming light polarization and phase effect the efficiency of photovoltaic cells?

Tags: electric-fields, solid-state-physics, laser, solar-cells, efficient-energy-use

As I understand it, standard photovoltaic cells depend on both the creation of electron-hole pairs and those pairs being created in the depletion zone in a P-N junction.

Is seems like the production of electron-hole pairs by photons would be in the direction of the electric field of that photon, so if the light was linearly polarized, those pairs would be produced along the direction of that electric field.

Further, if the electric field is in one direction, it would produce pairs in alignment with that direction, which (depending on the phase of the wave) might not be in the direction that is helpful for producing electricity (compared to the direction of the depletion zone).

Is this actually the case?  Does the polarization and phase of incoming light have an effect on efficiency?

For instance, would it be possible to set the polarization and phase of a laser to shine on a PV cell so that the efficiencies are much higher than light with the same energy distribution, but without a coherent polarization or phase (perhaps from an LED)?

---

Clarification

Standard PV cells have the plane of the p-n junction parallel to the plane of the surface of the cell.
[image]
Perhaps this isn't a thing, but I'm imagining something with strips of p-n junctions that are perpendicular to the surface of a cell.

Comment: Phase has no effect. Polarization would affect reflection from the front surface, that’s all. The absorption process does not work the way you currently envision it.

Comment: @Jon Custer 
Is it more of an elastic collision sort of thing, with the photon smacking the electron out of place?